# Moving Project file in Xcode Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, macos-mojave

I have somehow managed to get the Xcode project file for "My System" in a different folder from all the other project files.  Everything works but is there an easy way to get the files together in one folder (ie. either by moving "My System.xcodeproj" into the lower folder or moving all the other files up with it in the higher folder.

If I made this change, what parameters I would need to change inside Xcode.

I'm using Xcode 11.3.1 on Mojave and Objective-C (no storyboard).

I'm not sure if it is worth moving these or whether I should just leave it.

File and Folder Structure:

[image]

Comment: When I move the files up with the .xcodeproj file I get  an error that the .entitlements file  "could not be opened. Verify the value of the CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS build setting for target "My System" is correct and that the file exists on disk."

Comment: Same error when I move the xcodeproj file down with the rest of the files.  I'm assuming somewhere I need to modify a path statement but not sure where or if that is all that needs to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

The arrangement shown in your screen shot of the Finder is correct: a project folder, containing the project file (xcodeproj) along with a single folder that contains the actual code files. That is the standard. Don't mess with it.

Actually you shouldn't even *look* at it. Look at your project through Xcode, and let Xcode worry about where the files "really" are. Under *no* circumstances should you touch any of these files in the Finder or you will risk breaking the project entirely.

Comment: Thanks.  Good advice as I don't have any reason to change it I guess.